# Typescript: validate type after using type assertion

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to allow strict type checking on a value after having used a type assertion?

For example, sometimes I need to construct a function type that has attributes:

```
type FuncPlus = {
    (): void;
    anAttr: number;
    anotherAttr: Array<number>;
};

const f = (() => { }) as FuncPlus;
f.anAttr = 1;

f.anotherAttr.length # will error because `anotherAttr` is `undefined`
```

I want a clean way of constructing that still gives real type safety.

This is the closest that I've found, but it's not very "typescript-y":

```
const f: FuncPlus = Object.assign(
    () => { },
    {
        anAttr: 1,
        // without `anotherAttr` defined here, 
        // typescript will throw a compilation error, as desired
    }
)
```

Does anyone know another way?

Comment: When you use a type assertion, you will lose any ability to verify that the your object is constructed properly when initializing. Type assertion differs from type casting in that it is telling the compiler to treat the object as another type (and the compiler will not do anything to verify that you aren't wrong).

Comment: Why do you say that your resulting code isn't "typescript-y"?

Comment: Because it seems more like a work-around than a pattern that anyone designing typescript would have been planning on.

Comment: Well, it is kind of atypical to have static properties on functions. The only way to do that in an assignment is to do it using `Object.assign(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.assign` is the way `FuncPlus` type should be assigned, it's already concise enough.

If there is small set of properties, helper function can be used to skip property names:

```
const getFuncPlus = (fn: () => void, anAttr: number, anotherAttr: number[]): FuncPlus =>
 Object.assign(fn, { anAttr, anotherAttr });

getFuncPlus(() => {}, 1) // causes an error
```

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
type FuncPlus = {
  (): void;
  anAttr: undefined | number;
  anotherAttr: undefined | Array<number>;
};
```

satisfy your conditions?

```
const f = (() => {}) as FuncPlus;

f.anAttr = 1;
f.anAttr.toFixed() // good because of the above assignment

f.anotherAttr = "a" // errors - "a" is not assignable to type
f.anotherAttr.length // still errors // f.anotherAttr may be undefined

f.anotherAttr = []
f.anotherAttr.length // good
```

Comment: My hope is to have a strongly typed structure that doesn't allow `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
((f || {}).anotherAttr || {}).length
```